# "import" statements inside vue components in visual studio code are not updated when the referenced file is renamed/moved

Tags: visual-studio-code, import, vue-component

The vscode setting `javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled` (`always` or `prompt`) allows for automatic refactoring of all module import statements when the file that is referenced in the import is renamed or moved.
It works for .js files but how do you make this work for .vue files?

Comment: Have you got a solution for this problem? I seem to have the same problem.

Comment: Same here. Any solution?